# Black screen iOS 7 simulator

Tags: ios, ios7

When I try to launch the iOS 7 simulator on OS X 10.8.5 (just in case!) it does not show anything... Only a black screen shows up. Does anyone have this problem or knows anything about this? Thanks!

Comment: looks like you didnt add any view to the window. Without seeing code I cant tell more.

Comment: I'm just trying to run the SpriteKit example...

Comment: Have you checked if the simulator has been "locked"? I mean, it could be the lockscreen... Try to press CMD + Shift + H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the general issue facing in iOS 7 simulator. You have to wait for long time with black screen in iOS 7 simulator to run your application or quit simulator and relaunch your application.

Sometimes I have to delete application from simulator and then again have to run application from Xcode. It solves my problem, hope will help you also.

Comment: The problem is I can't even see the app installed on the simulator, because the simulator itself won't show up

Comment: Your app is not installing even once? Then wait for some long time to be installed, and hope it will, some times it takes 2 min. for me to show up my app in simulator with black screen.

Comment: I had to reinstall Xcode, but finally it worked...